Как скрыть блок DIV ? если дочерний блок div пустой


<div class="stories-view">
  
  <div class="title-and-link ads-stories"> <strong>Реклама на сайте</strong></div>
  <div class="recomend"><span class="description-info">Новая реклама</span></div>

        <div class="slider-user-stories"> 
          <div><?php echo $value["user_name"]; ?> <?php echo $value["user_name"]; ?></div> 
        </div>
   
</div>



Подскажите как скрыть блок stories-view если в блоке slider-user-stories пусто, если есть значения то показать блок stories-view полностью. Наверно это решается с помощью JS, или CSS подскажите как решить задачу. Может есть решение JS или PHP?

ты просто можешь проверить что в $value["user_name"] и $value["user_name"] и в зависимости от проверки - выводить или не выводить див <div class="stories-view">

К сожалению, этот вариант не подходит. было такое в размышлении, но не подходит.    эта структура для примера, с пробелом между значениями. чтобы было понятно что не возможно использовать :empty. Не знаю никак не могу найти подсказку или решение от чего оттолкнутся

так а почему не подходит-то? что мешает проверить нужный поля и выводить див или не выводить?

В размышлении было, не сильно уверен в своих знаниях как это сделать
